# Breakpoints in event handlers don't get triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my React.js application and I've noticed that when trying to debug my tests `debugger` statements in event handlers don't get triggered.

Is this expected behavior or a known bug? I've googled far and wide and couldn't really find any answers or explanations to this, apart from other issues with debugging.

I've created a minimal test case here: https://github.com/trodrigues/jest-test

Answer (score 0):

So a few minutes after I posted this I noticed Node.js 7.5.0 was out which literally fixes this.